# onClick Button not working

Tags: android, button

i'm new on this "World" and i'm having serious troubles with this button, i've done more buttons with Android Studio, but this one is driving me crazy, i don't know how to solve this issue, could anyone of you help me please?

.java (I just wanted to create a toast saying "sent successfully", and then create the onClickButton to do the rest of stuff)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);



    final Button btAceptar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btEnviar);
    btAceptar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btAceptar.setOnClickListener(this);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Datos enviados correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });






}
    public void onClickEnviar(View v){
    final EditText txtCognom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCognom);
    final EditText txtNom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNom);
    final EditText txtEdat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEdat);
    final EditText txtTelefon = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTelefon);
    final EditText txtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);

    Intent iIntent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, EnvioFormulario.class);

    // Bundle per al cognom i posem la informació al intent
    Bundle bEnviat = new Bundle();
    bEnviat.putString("Cognom", txtCognom.getText().toString());
    bEnviat.putString("Nom", txtNom.getText().toString());
    bEnviat.putString("Edat", txtEdat.getText().toString());
    bEnviat.putString("Telefon", txtTelefon.getText().toString());
    bEnviat.putString("Email", txtEmail.getText().toString());
    iIntent.putExtras(bEnviat);


    // Start a la activitat per a que començi
    startActivity(iIntent);

}
```

If you need another part of my code to try to help me, i'll post it!

Thanks.

Comment: Most likely unrelated, but why do you set the listener again once the button is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the setting of the onClickListener from inside the listener. That's not needed. Just keep this part:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    final Button btAceptar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btEnviar);
    btAceptar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           onClickEnviar();
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Datos enviados correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    });
}

public void onClickEnviar() {
    final EditText txtCognom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCognom);
    final EditText txtNom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNom);
    final EditText txtEdat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEdat);
    final EditText txtTelefon = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTelefon);
    final EditText txtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);

    Intent iIntent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, EnvioFormulario.class);

    // Bundle per al cognom i posem la informació al intent
    Bundle bEnviat = new Bundle();
    bEnviat.putString("Cognom", txtCognom.getText().toString());
    bEnviat.putString("Nom", txtNom.getText().toString());
    bEnviat.putString("Edat", txtEdat.getText().toString());
    bEnviat.putString("Telefon", txtTelefon.getText().toString());
    bEnviat.putString("Email", txtEmail.getText().toString());
    iIntent.putExtras(bEnviat);


    // Start a la activitat per a que començi
    startActivity(iIntent);

}
```

Comment: Witch one?

btAceptar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
btAceptar.setOnClickListener(this);

Thanks

Comment: the btAceptar.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: I did it, but it still without change the activity neither the Intents / bundles
When I click on the Button it only appears the toast...

Comment: If you want the toast and want to use send the info over, just use the updated code I posted.  You could also put the Toast code inside the method as well.

Comment: So I have to create method "onClickEnviar" then MY activity? but it create another private void onClickEnviar() {
    }

Comment: Still not working the changes on code... could you help me please?

Comment: what is the current behavior?

Comment: The Button still not working and when i click it, the app crashes... What part of the code should I show so you could help me?